# How do you measure the acceleration of two objects with different masses?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I would like to know how to measure the acceleration of two objects with different masses...(and the formula that's used.)

For instance a steel ball that, say...weighs 67g and a wooden ball that weighs 5.4g.......
 The steel ball takes 134 milliseconds to cover 10cm when it's dropped to the floor and the wooden ball takes 128 milliseconds........how do you measure the acceleration of these two different masses?

Comment: It takes 134 milliseconds to fall to the floor? Are they traveling horizontally or vertically?

Comment: As it is, the question is unclear. You need to specify more information: Did they start from rest? Are they traveling horizontally or vertically? Note that if you can figure out a problem using kinematics, you probably don't need forces to figure out the acceleration.

Comment: They are traveling verticaly

Comment: Then the acceleration will be exactly the same, barring air resistance. Either that or error on the part of the observer must account for the time discrepancy, assuming both were dropped at the same speed, and from the same height above Earth's surface. Mass shouldn't play into it.

Comment: Well I used a device that measures the acceleration of the gravity so I suppose there is air resistance. ...

Comment: And I measured each ball one at a time

Answer (score 1):

Just use the standard equation: $y=y_0-v_0t-1/2 a t^2$, you have all the data to solve for $a$ on each of the two cases ($v_0=0$, I assume, because it was dropped from rest). The two accfelerations should be the same and equal to g, however I am assuming this is not the case due to either air friction, or buoyancy.

Comment: This is a clearer explanation of what I meant.

Comment: So it's:   y=0 - 0 * 0.134s  - 1/2 * 9.81m/s^2 * 0.134s^2...........I hope I'm not wrong....I'm sort of a beginner at this

Comment: y=0 and $y_0=10 cm$ the starting height, and then you need to find a, a in not g because of the friction, that is why I used a intead of g, otherwise there would be nothing to solve